# Two unordered lists on the same page, one inline and one initial

Tags: html, css, html-lists, display

I'm trying to set up two un-ordered lists, side by side in columns.

I want to set the list on the left to `display: initial;`, and the list on the right to `display: inline;`.

Have a look at my [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/61wuxujq/).

```
ul > li {
        display: initial;
    }

ul > li .hashtag {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 5px 5px;      
}
```

I've tried it in the stylesheet, head and inline. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Checked the fiddle, what list are you pertaining in "list on the right"? There are 3 list on left, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @webfrogs you want this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/mebdrkxg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.hashtag` is a `ul` class, your trying to apply CSS on you `li` child, which won't work. Try changing your selector that way :

```css
ul.keyword  {
  display: initial;
}

ul.hashtag > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 5px;      
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Below is a list of the most common keywords.</h3>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <ul class="keyword">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <ul class="keyword">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h3>Below is a list of the most common hashtags used. <small>Click to copy</small></h3>
        <ul class="hashtag">
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 1</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 2</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 3</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 4</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 5</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 6</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 7</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 8</button></li>
          <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 9</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Turns out, this is what works:   `ul > li {
   list-style: none;
  }
  ul.hashtag li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 5px;
  }`

I've updated the fiddle here. Notice the list on the right is displaying inline, and the list on the left is in it's native format: [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/61wuxujq/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working fiddle
You need to update following html to get it

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Below is a list of the most common keywords.</h3>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="keyword">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                    <li>Item 5</li>
                    <li>Item 6</li>
                    <li>Item 7</li>
                    <li>Item 8</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="keyword">
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                    <li>Item 2</li>
                    <li>Item 3</li>
                    <li>Item 4</li>
                    <li>Item 5</li>
                    <li>Item 6</li>
                    <li>Item 7</li>
                    <li>Item 8</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3>Below is a list of the most common hashtags used. <small>Click to copy</small></h3>
            <ul class="hashtag">
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 1</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 2</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 3</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 4</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 5</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 6</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 7</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 8</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">#Button 9</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61wuxujq/2/)**